# Change database for each user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am developing a multi-company website in which each company has its database and when the user logs in, then the database will be changed depending on the "company.id" field that each user will have. The problem is that when a user of a company "X" logs on and then logs another user of a company "Y" then it changes database affecting all logged in users, every time it is changed Database changes for all users instead of changing only for the user who logs on
this is my code to change the database:

```
def set_database
   if user_signed_in?
      company = (current_user.company_id).to_s.to_sym 
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(company)
    else
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:'232')
    end
 end
```

The variable "company" will take the value of "company_id" of the user and will make a connection with the database of the company, for example company has a value to "32" then will make the connection in the database.yml with:

```
'32':
  adapter: sqlserver
  mode: dblib
  dataserver:
  host: host
  port: 1433
  database: database
  username: user
  password: pass
  timeout: 60000
  azure: true
```

How could logon each user without affecting others who have a different database?

Comment: Not sure if this is a good solution but maybe store the users database info in a session and then reference it for queries?

Answer (score 1):

Judging based on your knowledge of rails, you likely don't want to be rolling your own multi-tenancy (by database) at this point in your application (even [basecamp a very large rails app doesn't do that](https://twitter.com/dhh/status/651805428968521728)). That's something that can get very big and hairy and doesn't need to happen until you've hit large enough scale. As well, there's a cost incurred creating and tearing down database connections which is going to be expensive for every request.

Instead I'd suggest using a [multi-tenancy gem](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/multitenant) of which there are a few:

- [Apartment](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/apartment)
- [acts_as_tenant](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/acts_as_tenant)

Or as an alternative doing [multi-tenancy without database segmentation](http://davidlesches.com/blog/multitenancy-in-rails).

Comment: thanks for answer, this gem allows me to change database for each user?